# How to fix my boot situation?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, hard-drive

Okay so the situation is:
On my old computer, I used to have a 2TB HDD, that had a dual boot installation with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 20.2.
On my new computer, which is a Dell OptiPlex 1040, I took this drive and installed it as a secondary drive without formatting it, because I didn't want to lose data stored on it (I do not really have capacity to store that almost terabyte of data on it anywhere else). However, it had two 1TB partitions - boot partition that was NTFS with Windows - I wiped this one - and the second ext4 partition with Linux - this one I didn't wipe. The primary drive in this new Dell is a 222 GB Hitachi SSD with preinstalled Windows 10.
I recently tried installing new version of Ubuntu on this new computer, 20.4 - and the installation gave me an option to install it alongside old 20.2 that it still for some reason found by splitting the old ext4 partition into two new ones. Since I liked the idea of keeping data from that partition, I did that.

The thing is, it doesn't work. The Dell bios has two main options for boot sequence - Legacy boot, where selecting the HDD option which allows me to boot into Grub menu, but neither option called "Ubuntu" that appears to be the old 20.2, nor the option to boot into the new 20.4 work - in both cases, starting Ubuntu causes a cursor to appear in text mode and I can hear hard drive working, but nothing happens. Pressing Ctrl C causes a text mode login screen to appear, but I can't get GUI. Also the Grub menu does not notice Windows at all. In contrast UEFI option has "Windows Boot Manager" option, which boots straight to Windows.

Also trying out different boot options, I noticed that the Bios seems to notice entirely different boot sequence options every time I check it with no rhyme or reason.

At this point I realized I probably messed something up (I'm assuming the mistake was not wiping the ext4 partition when installing Ubuntu on the new computer, which in hindsight was probably stupid of me). What is the correct way to proceed now? Is my best course of action just backing up important data on cloud and formatting both my drives clean and going with a clean install, starting with new Windows and then Ubuntu? Is there a simpler solution I can try?

Comment: Please be precise with details; Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format such as Ubuntu 20.04 representing the 2020-April release (the exception being some *specialist* snap only products that year the *year* format).  There was no release in 2020-February (ie. 20.02) so are you using Ubuntu at all?

Comment: You can boot your ```Ubuntu 20.04.2``` and ```Ubuntu 20.04.4``` by using ```super_grub2_disk_hybrid_2.02s10.iso``` or an ```Ikki_Boot_10.2.iso``` using the ```super-grub2-disk```-program. Make a usb-stick with one of them. ( ```Ikki_Boot_10.2.iso``` is larger 2.6 Gb but has a lot of programs for troubleshooting, ```super_grub2_disk_hybrid_2.02s10.iso``` is only 20 Mb) It will detect all bootable Operating Systems on your computer.<br>Once booted in one of your Ubuntu-releases, you repair ```Grub```.<br>I always choose ```other options``` during install of any Linux-distro (I havefull control).